# Sending multiple files through network - time to time

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have program that create screenshots and some txt files and send it throught socket. But every time I must connect to server to send data. (connect -> send -> disconnect)

current solution:
server:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)){
            while(true){
                new Echoer(serverSocket.accept()).start();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("Server exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class Server extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;

    public Server(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " -> " + "CONNECTED");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String main = "tests";
            DataInputStream dis;
            BufferedInputStream bis;
            //while (true) {

            bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            String directory = dis.readUTF(); //read directory
            String dirPath = main + "/" + directory; //main dir
            String tmp = dirPath;

            //create directory
            if (!new File(dirPath).exists()) {
                new File( dirPath).mkdir();
                new File( dirPath + "/o").mkdir();
                new File( dirPath+ "/n").mkdir();
            }


            int fileCount = dis.readInt();
            File[] files = new File[fileCount]; //array for files


            for (File f : files) {
                long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                String fileName = dis.readUTF();

                dirPath = tmp;

                f = new File(dirPath + "/" + fileName);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                for (int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) bos.write(bis.read());

                bos.close();
                fos.close();
            }
            dis.close();
            System.out.println("Received file");
            //}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("->" + e.getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

client

```
public class Connection {

    private String path;
    private List<String> files;
    private Socket socket;
    private Config config;

    @SneakyThrows
    public Connection(String path, List<String> files){
        this.config = LoadConfig.getInstance().getConfig();
        this.path = path;
        this.files = files;
        //ip, port from config
        socket = new Socket(
                config.getServer().getUrl(),
                config.getServer().getPort()
        );
    }
    
    public void send() {
        
        BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        try {

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            
            //map paths to files
            List<File> filesList = files.stream().map(e -> new File(path + "/"+ e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            dos.writeUTF(ComputerInfo.userName()); //send user name
            dos.writeInt(filesList.size()); //send amount of elements

            for(File f: filesList){
                long length = f.length(); //one file size
                dos.writeLong(length);

                String name = f.getName();
                dos.writeUTF(name); //send file name

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                int theByte = 0;
                while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte);

                bis.close();
            }
            dos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I want to send files from time to time, depending on what the algorithm returns. It means send files in irregular times. It means send 1 file wait 5 min sent 4 files wait 1s send 3 ... But I don't know how to do it. I created also client using blockingqueue and other parts of program add data to it.

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private Config config;
    protected BlockingQueue<Data> queue;
    private BufferedOutputStream bos;
    private DataOutputStream dos;

    @SneakyThrows
    public Connection(BlockingQueue<Data> queue) {
        this.config = LoadConfig.getInstance().getConfig();

        socket = new Socket(
                config.getServer().getUrl(),
                config.getServer().getPort()
        );
        this.queue = queue;
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public void run() {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

        while (true) {

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                //this.send();
                System.out.println(queue.size());
            }

        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    private void send() {
        Data loadData = queue.take();

        List<File> filesList = loadData.getList().stream().map(e -> new File(loadData.getPath() + "/" + e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        dos.writeUTF(ComputerInfo.userName());
        dos.writeInt(filesList.size());

        for (File f : filesList) {
            long length = f.length();
            dos.writeLong(length);

            String name = f.getName();
            dos.writeUTF(name);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            int theByte = 0;
            while ((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte);

            bis.close();
            fis.close();

        }
        dos.close();
    }
```

Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you don't understand?  When you actually start sending files, what goes wrong?  What happens, and what do you want to happen instead?  Where in the code do you think the problem might be?

Comment: In current implementation when I create some kind of file I connect to server and send data and I must disconnect at the end.
But I want connect once starting app (connection in separate thread) second example with blockingqueue.
And in that thread waiting for data from queue. When ex. in main thread I create file, thread with socket should send data.
But it's not working I have An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine or sometimes socket is close. Now I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Try [setKeepAlive(true)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean))